# Breadcrumbs in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is there any way to get Breadcrumbs in **Visual Studio** 2022 (**NOT** VSCode, I know VSCode has it) for C++? I am surprised that such a useful feature is not easily available.

[image: Breadcrumbs in VSCode]

Comment: Despite the names, Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code have almost nothing in common. What's easy to do in one might be an utter <expletive deleted> in the other.

Comment: Send VS Feedback asking for this!  It's literally a feature the editor team has been discussing for months, but they can always use more signal from users to prioritize new features (it's already been bumped a few times).

Comment: Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio are different products. You may need third-party plugins or propose new features to the developer community.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Something similar is in the upper part of the text editor. It gives you Project->Class (or other space)->method

My version is VS 2022 Professional

Comment: Ah, the navigation toolbar. It lists the functions in the file but not show the path to the current line like breadcrumbs do.